# To display Jquery fancybox popup

Tags: jquery, facebook, fancybox

I got a simple question about jquery fancybox. In my recent project I have facebook share link in every details page of my photo gallery and I am using fancybox to display the whole detail page as a pop up. But when I sharing link to facebook, I want that link from facebook to redirect back to related detail page as jquery pop up. 
I've already got the correct url with id of detail page linking to normal detail page. I know theres a way to get it as popup but I couldn't find out... Any help please...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

OK, here is the code i used...

```
<script type="text/javascript">
$(function() {
    var i = jQuery.url.param("id")
    var x = ".thumb a#"+i;
    var y = ".lastthumb a#"+i;

    if(i!=""){
        $(x).trigger('click');
        $(y).trigger('click');
    }
});
</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can add an anchor tag in your URL specifying the fancybox you want to open (e.g http://yoursite.com/#myfancybox1).

Then you can use some jQuery plugin to get this value (like https://github.com/allmarkedup/jQuery-URL-Parser) and get the `jQuery.url.attr('anchor');`.

Once your DOM is ready, just check for the URL if there's an anchor (and the anchor is linked to an existing Fancybox). If then open the fancybox :)

Comment: Thanks I gonna give it a try :)

Comment: I tried but the url http://yoursite.com/#myfancybox1... only #myfancybox1 is missing when I shared it on facebook. The plugin itself is working fine though.

Comment: $fb = "http://www.facebook.com/sharer.php?u=www.mysite.com/details.php?id=".$id."#thumb"; This is what I did for facebook sharing.

Comment: Encode the Sharp (#) to `%23` - http://www.facebook.com/sharer.php?u=www.mysite.com/details.php?id=%22.$id.%22%23thumb%22

Comment: any news about this question?

Comment: i have fixed this just by tracking the id using yr jquery url plugin :) thanks

Comment: replacing the sharp with %23 didn't work ? also could you vote + set answered ? :)